# Jmeter beanshell to match and replace

Tags: jmeter, javabeans

I rarely do scripting and I have problem using reg expression using Jmeter's beanshell.
Basically, I have an output of 16 digits. I wanted to search the string, separate every 2nd character, and prepend with '**0x**' followed by a space, repeat for all 16 digits, lastly using vars.put into a self defined parameters. I have managed to do this in bash easily but not able to find solution with Beanshell Jmeter.

```
//  get current date
var d = new Date();
// convert to epoch
var militime = d.getTime();
// convert to 16digit
//var nowtime1 = (long.valueOf(militime) * 1000);
var nowtime1 = militime * 1000;

var nowtime1 = nowtime1.replace(/({0,2})/g,"x0"); //I'm unsure of the syntax here
```

Does anyone has suggestion to improve?

This is sample output from my bash script using *sed* to format:

```
1495207922508835
0x14 0x95 0x20 0x79 0x22 0x50 0x88 0x35
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Beanshell is some form of [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) when it comes to creating JMeter scripts, you should consider using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](http://groovy-lang.org/) instead as Groovy is less resource intensive, has much better performance and it is more Java-compliant.

Coming back to your question, Groovy implementation of your requirement would be something like:

```
def now = "1495207922508835"

def result = new StringBuilder()
now.split("(?<=\\G..)").each {
    result.append("0x").append(it).append(" ")
}
log.info(result.toString())
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy string split and concatenate]

See [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide to learn about why and how you should be using Groovy in JMeter tests.

---

NB: adding `0x` doesn't really convert an integer into hex, you might want to consider [Integer.toHexString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString-int-) method instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify current time retrieval to `System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000`. Second, you are trying to manipulate number as if it's a string, but then you need to convert it to string. Regex itself is almost right. So the whole script looks like this:

```
now = "" + (java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000);
result = now.replaceAll("(.{2})", "0x$1 ");
```

Example:

```
now              result
1495215390956000 0x14 0x95 0x21 0x53 0x90 0x95 0x60 0x00 
1495215441281000 0x14 0x95 0x21 0x54 0x41 0x28 0x10 0x00
```

Comment: Just to confirm, is there any way to retrieve time in microseconds using javascript?

Comment: You can't use JavaScript in BeanShell: BeanShell is a Java-like language. If you want to use JavaScript, switch to JSR223 post-processor as Dmitri T suggested.